# How to enforce GitHub "Release title" format rules

Tags: github, github-actions

How can I require the *Release Title* match a particular format (regex, etc)?  If a user tries to set an invalid *Release Title* they should get a failure notification.  This must apply when the release is published but ideally it would apply to pre-release and drafts too.

Some Github action needs to be registered here?
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#release

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, how big is your team and why is this a concern of yours? GitHub releases aren't like git commits and tags (which are immutable, so getting-it-right-first-time matters), instead [you can always edit and rename a Release at any point in the future](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/releasing-projects-on-github/managing-releases-in-a-repository)... so _why_?

Comment: Unfortunately github.event.release.name is referred to in other Actions and if it's wrong it screws things up so it can't just be changed later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a github action that is triggered when releases are published:

```
name: Validate Name
on:
  release:
    types: [published]
...
```

In that action test or change the name value as needed using [actions/github-script](https://github.com/actions/github-script).